# How to Compare Each Line and Get the Last Full Sentence in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a file that contains the following.

```
BEFORE
BEFORE THE
BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT
BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON
BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON BRITAIN'S
BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON BRITAIN'S RELATIONS
BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON BRITAIN'S RELATIONS WITH
BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON BRITAIN'S RELATIONS WITH SCOTLAND
BRITAIN'S RELATIONS WITH SCOTLAND FOLLOWING
BRITAIN'S RELATIONS WITH SCOTLAND FOLLOWING THE
BRITAIN'S RELATIONS WITH SCOTLAND FOLLOWING THE REFERENDUM
SCOTLAND FOLLOWING THE REFERENDUM VOTE.
SCOTLAND FOLLOWING THE REFERENDUM VOTE. LAST
SCOTLAND FOLLOWING THE REFERENDUM VOTE. LAST MONTH
SCOTLAND FOLLOWING THE REFERENDUM VOTE. LAST MONTH SCOTLAND
REFERENDUM VOTE. LAST MONTH SCOTLAND VOTED
REFERENDUM VOTE. LAST MONTH SCOTLAND VOTED IN
REFERENDUM VOTE. LAST MONTH SCOTLAND VOTED IN FAVOR
REFERENDUM VOTE. LAST MONTH SCOTLAND VOTED IN FAVOR OF
REFERENDUM VOTE. LAST MONTH SCOTLAND VOTED IN FAVOR OF STAYING
REFERENDUM VOTE. LAST MONTH SCOTLAND VOTED IN FAVOR OF STAYING WITH
LAST MONTH SCOTLAND VOTED IN FAVOR OF STAYING WITH THE
LAST MONTH SCOTLAND VOTED IN FAVOR OF STAYING WITH THE UNITED
LAST MONTH SCOTLAND VOTED IN FAVOR OF STAYING WITH THE UNITED KINGDOM
LAST MONTH SCOTLAND VOTED IN FAVOR OF STAYING WITH THE UNITED KINGDOM AFTER
LAST MONTH SCOTLAND VOTED IN FAVOR OF STAYING WITH THE UNITED KINGDOM AFTER THE
```

And I am trying to ignore the repetitive ones and get only the last full sentence. So it would look like this

```
BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON BRITAIN'S RELATIONS WITH SCOTLAND
BRITAIN'S RELATIONS WITH SCOTLAND FOLLOWING THE REFERENDUM
SCOTLAND FOLLOWING THE REFERENDUM VOTE. LAST MONTH SCOTLAND
REFERENDUM VOTE. LAST MONTH SCOTLAND VOTED IN FAVOR OF STAYING WITH
LAST MONTH SCOTLAND VOTED IN FAVOR OF STAYING WITH THE UNITED KINGDOM AFTER THE
```

I am seeing if the previous line is in the next line, and if so I want to keep iterating, and if not, I want to add the last sentence to the list. However, my logic below is not working.

```
with open("data.txt", 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    data_list = []
    comp_word = "BEFORE"
    for line in data:
        if comp_word in line:
            comp_word == line
        elif comp_word not in line:
            data_list.append(line)

print(data_list)
```

What would be an alternative way to approach this problem?

Comment: Have you checked to see that whit is in `data` and `line` are what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
data = []
with open("data.txt") as infile:
    cache = ''
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        # if the current line is an extention of the last line, update and ignore
        if line.startswith(cache):
            cache = line
        else:
            # we see a brand new content line. Write out the cache and reset it to the current line's contents
            data.append(cache)
            cache = line
    data.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the entire line and the `startswith` method.

```
best = ""     # Longest sentence so far
with open("data.txt", 'r') as f:
    data_list = []
    for line in f:
        new_line = line.strip()
        if not new_line.startswith(best):
            data_list.append(best)
        best = new_line
```